# Using mr.migrator and transmogrify.filesystem to import images (especially news items with images)

Tags: plone, transmogrifier

I'm looking at this example (https://github.com/aclark4life/mr_migrator_demo/tree/master/data), which mostly does what I need. What I'm not seeing is how to include images or news items with images.

Would appreciates a few pointers in the right direction.

Comment: `transmogrify.filesystem` already handles images directly. What specific problems have you run into?

Comment: perhaps I haven't done enough reading of the manual :). My problem is creating a news item that has an attached image. News Items have a custom image and image caption field.

Comment: Yes, that's a little more complex, as that requires *two* files; for the images you would issue a transmogrifier entry that has the path of the parent news item and just the image field filled for the content updater to set just that image field on the already-created news item.

Comment: @DavidBain: Yight want to have a look at niteoweb.transmogrifier.simpleusage and search on pypi for 'transmogrifier', to get more blueprints, HTH.